# "Fatal Error: infinite loop detected" via lessphp

Tags: css, less, lessphp

I'm try to compile this .less code to .css via lessphp and get this error:

```
Fatal Error:
====================
infinite loop detected: @pos-x: failed at `background-position: @pos-x 0; }` line: 3
```

Here is my code.

```
@pos-x : 0;
@w : 30px;
.a { background-position: @pos-x 0; }

@pos-x: @pos-x - @w;
.b { background-position: @pos-x 0; }
```

What's wrong with it? Can i use varable overriding in LESS?

Comment: Your best option is just to define a new variable. Personally, I declare all variables before writing any CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@pos-x: @pos-x - @w;` is not allowed. [The documentation states](http://lesscss.org/#docs), "Note that variables in LESS are actually ‘constants’ in that they can only be defined once."

I believe what happens with LESS in such a case is essentially this:

```
@pos-x: 0;
@pos-x: @pos-x - 30px; puts it into this loop...
        @pos-x = -30px - 30px ...
        @pox-x = -60px - 30px ...
        @pox-x = -90px - 30px ... etc.
```

Thus, it continually recalculates the `@pos-x` trying to come to a final resolution which is never reached. Everytime it is reassigned, it attempts to reevaluate based off that new assignment.

So do something like this:

```
@pos1-x : 0;
@w : 30px;
.a { background-position: @pos1-x 0; }

@pos2-x: @pos1-x - @w;
.b { background-position: @pos2-x 0; }
```

Comment: Intentional or not, lessPHP actually allows variables to be redefined - although it does compute the actual (last declared) value before applying it. In any case, this is still a correct answer.

Comment: You can paste this into the [online compiler](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) to see it: `@base: #fff; @base: @base; p{color:@base}`

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Yes, I have questioned before what they have meant by that statement, as one can "redifine" (overwrite) a variable in LESS. But I think this case here is perhaps part of what they intended to communicate.

Comment: Right, for example (at least with lessPHP), this: `@c: #fff; p {color:@c} @c: #000;` produces the CSS `p {
  color: #000;
}`

Comment: Right, the first piece of code was meant to demonstrate the loop and your correct-ness. The second was meant to demo "redefining variables" behavior.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: your first code gives the infinite loop error on that compiler.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Okay! We are on the same page then.